# Change value of CSS subclass in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So here I have a simple class / subclass that is in a style.css.  I can't assign the element an id or define it in the CSS as an id using #.  So no easy getElementById().  I need to change the "top" value to various sizes dynamically using javascript or jquery.

```
.slider-edit .bx-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 265px;
    left: -32px;
    width: 31px;
    height: 31px;
    text-indent: -999999px;
    background: url(../images/icon_arrow_left.png) no-repeat 0 -31px;
}
```

I've searched the site and web, trying things like this with no luck.

```
$("slider-edit bx-prev").css("top","100px");
$(".slider-edit .bx-prev").css("top","100px");
document.getElementsByClassName('slider-edit bx-prev').style.top = "100px";
document.getElementsByClassName('.slider-edit .bx-prev').style.top = "100px";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$(".slider-edit .bx-prev").css("top","100px");` works just fine.

Comment: Thanks.. turns out that the style wasn't applied until after the document was ready.  So I've been banging my head trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.. haha.  Thanks, you guys got me pointed right. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this one is working fine:

```
$('.slider-edit .bx-prev').css("top", "100px");
```

Comment: Thanks.. turns out that the style wasn't applied until after the document was ready. So I've been banging my head trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.. haha. Thanks, you guys got me pointed right. :)

Comment: Ahh yeah that's caught me before too. I actually didn't realise you'd already tried this answer when I posted it!